# ASPNET cookie validation

Tags: session, model-view-controller, cookies, webforms, forms-authentication

In forms authentication, after authenticating a user/password, a cookie is created and sent to client machine. Can any one answer below questions on validating cookies.

1. How is this client cookie validated by aspnet on subsequent request after successful login? Does aspnet compare contents of cookie with any data store?
2. On server, where does aspnet maintain authenticated users details to validate the cookies?
3. What details are placed in cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3. The cookie set by [`FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.formsauthentication.setauthcookie?view=netframework-4.8) contains a string representation of the encrypted and signed [`FormsAuthenticationTicket`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket?view=netframework-4.8) object which in turn represents the authentication ticket that is used by forms authentication to identify an authenticated user. The ticket object is initialized with the associated user name, version number, expiration date, issue date, a boolean value on whether the ticket will be stored in a persistent cookie or not and any user-specific data. Check out the [constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.formsauthenticationticket.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_Security_FormsAuthenticationTicket__ctor_System_Int32_System_String_System_DateTime_System_DateTime_System_Boolean_System_String_) of `FormsAuthenticationTicket` for details. Other than that the cookie typically contains properties such as its virtual path, the associated domain and whether the cookie should only be transmitted over an HTTPS connection.

1 and 2. On each request the server looks for the cookie and decrypts the authentication ticket  found in it. Also, the server checks whether the ticket is still valid based on its expiration value. No comparison to and/or validation against any server-side maintained data takes place, whatsoever.

Comment: 1 and 2. After decrypting the authencation ticket, if there is no cookie content validation on server-side, what is preventing a fake hacker cookie from accessing the application?

<br> How is the user context built from the cookie ie if JohnDoe's authenicated cookie is received by server, how JohnDoe's authencation info(ex: JohnDoe autheticated previously) is built.

Comment: @nagiahs As said, the cookie content (i.e. the ticket) is encrypted (using the Rinjdael (AES) algorithm in ASP.NET 2.0, by default). So tampering with it is (very) hard, I guess.  Nevertheless, the cookie itself is not unless HTTPS is used. Make sure you enable SSL if you are worried about cookie stealing. The ticket data is used to build the identity of the authenticated user: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.formsauthenticationmodule?view=netframework-4.8